# Recorrer números de secuencia

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger, plsql

Tengo una duda de que forma puedo recorrer los valores que me de una secuencia cuando elimine un valor.

Tengo la secuencia.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SIT_USER_DATA_SEQ
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;
```

y el trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER SIT_USER_DATA_TRG
BEFORE INSERT ON SIT_USER_DATA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT SIT_USER_DATA_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :new.SUD_ID
  FROM dual;
END;
```

Cuando inserta un registro coloca el id correctamente, pero al momento de eliminar un registro ese id que se elimino desaparece.

¿Cómo podría recorrer el id para que cuando se elimine el registro se recorran los id?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: a que te refieres? que es lo que quieres lograr cuando se elimine un registro?